# How to filter out non-readable screen-fonts?

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-10.1-berlin

In a Delphi 10.1.2 VCL Forms Application, I fill a `TComboBox` with the `Screen.Fonts` list and display the font items using their own font-faces:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddFontsToComboList;
end;

procedure TForm2.AddFontsToComboList;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to Screen.Fonts.Count - 1 do
    begin
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(Screen.Fonts[i]);
    end;
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
// ComboBox1.Style must be csOwnerDrawVariable
begin
  with ComboBox1 do
  begin
    Canvas.fillrect(rect);
    Canvas.Font.Style := [fsbold];
    Canvas.Font.Name  := ComboBox1.Items[Index];
    Canvas.Textout(rect.Left, rect.Top, ComboBox1.Items[Index]);
  end;
end;
```

This is the result:

[image]

You can see that there are some missing items. In the above screenshot, the missing font is **Cambria Math**.

So how can I filter out those empty items?
And how can I filter out those items which are unreadable?
And how can I filter out the fonts which contain only symbols?
You know what I mean.

Comment: You just cannot see it. It's rendered but it's very height in pixels. Try to setup that font for your combo box. On my machine the combo box height grown to 69 pixels whilst the height of the font at size 8 is just a few (lazy to measure). In your combo box you need to measure item height and return there the height of the font.

Comment: You are right! Do you know a way to display these fonts with a smaller ItemHeight?

Comment: Displaying in that combo is one thing (where **I think you will need to apply manual cropping**), using such font is another. Think about what can happen if that combo box will be used e.g. for setting edit box font and you display it in low height and when the user selects that font, the control unpredictably grows. Is that what you want? Cannot that happen with the usage of your control?

Comment: No, that's not what I really want. So how to filter out those "oversized XXL" fonts?

Comment: You can measure the font metrics and only if the height is lower than the item size, you can add it to the list. Or you can have variable item size but in that case you won't see it fully in the combo edit.

Comment: I think that measuring the font metrics while adding the fonts to the combo-list would be the best solution, as I cannot use those oversized fonts anyway. Do you know how to measure the font metrics? Wouldn't that slow down the process of adding the fonts to the combo-list too much?

Comment: See [`GetTextMetrics()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144941.aspx) (more generally, [Fonts and text metrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn614134.aspx))

Comment: @user1580348: Yes, it would slow down filling the combobox. But how much is something you'll have to measure. I don't think it will make a big dfference.

Comment: @Rudy, there's not much options here. Either you measure when adding, measure when control asks for item size or do not measure and see an "empty" item :)

Comment: @Victoria: Not many options, but it will certainly make a difference.